# Create a Line FeatureClass from IPointCollection

Tags: arcobjects, vba

I want to create a new line layer from a point layer. I store the points in an IPointCollection. I want to use that IPointCollection to create a line IFeatureClass. I know how to create a single Feature and how to put it in a layer, but this doesn't work.

Comment: Are you attempting to connect multiple points with one single line? How do you identify which points you want to connect from your point data? Is there a spatial relationship or is it related to an attribute of your points?

Comment: I want two points connects to a line. To identify i get the featureclass of the point layer and loop through with a for loop like: [code]
  for i=0 to featureclass.FeatureCount(Nothing)-1
    set point = featureclass.GetFeature(i).Shape
  Next

  Dim line As ILine
  Set line = new Line
  line.fromPoint point1
  line.toPoint point2
  [/code]

 and so on

Answer (score 2):

Ok, since we are talking about drawing one line between two points here and assuming you already know how to get your two points:

First, [create your brand new feature class](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//000100000419000000):

```
Public Function CreateStandaloneFeatureClass(ByVal workspace As IWorkspace, ByVal featureClassName As String, ByVal fieldsCollection As IFields, ByVal shapeFieldName As String) As IFeatureClass
    Dim featureWorkspace As IFeatureWorkspace = CType(workspace, IFeatureWorkspace)
    Dim fcDesc As IFeatureClassDescription = New FeatureClassDescriptionClass()
    Dim ocDesc As IObjectClassDescription = CType(fcDesc, IObjectClassDescription)

    ' Use IFieldChecker to create a validated fields collection.
    Dim fieldChecker As IFieldChecker = New FieldCheckerClass()
    Dim enumFieldError As IEnumFieldError = Nothing
    Dim validatedFields As IFields = Nothing
    fieldChecker.ValidateWorkspace = workspace
    fieldChecker.Validate(fieldsCollection, enumFieldError, validatedFields)

    ' The enumFieldError enumerator can be inspected at this point to determine
    ' which fields were modified during validation.
    Dim featureClass As IFeatureClass = featureWorkspace.CreateFeatureClass(featureClassName, validatedFields, ocDesc.InstanceCLSID, ocDesc.ClassExtensionCLSID, esriFeatureType.esriFTSimple, shapeFieldName, "")
    Return featureClass
End Function
```

Now you have a feature class. Query your IPointCollection for the two IPoint features that you want to make a line from. [Now create your line and store it in the featureclass.](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/28358-Add-line-feature-to-polyline-feature-class-VB-VBA)

```
Dim FirstPoint As IPoint = 'get your first point from IPointCollection
Dim SecondPoint As IPoint = 'get your second point from IPointCollection

Dim polyline As IPolyline = new Polyline
 polyline.FromPoint = FirstPoint
 polyline.ToPoint = SecondPoint
 Dim feature As IFeature = featureClass.CreateFeature
 feature.Shape = polyline
 feature.Store
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I accomplished this task in VB.NET. I have an input featureclass containing the points (pPointFClass) and an output featureclass that will contain the lines (pLineFClass). This is part of a larger tool that would take the attributes of the first point and apply those attributes to the resultant line.

```
Private pIFBuffer As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeatureBuffer
Private pIFCursor As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeatureCursor

pIFCursor = pLineFClass.Insert(True)
pIFBuffer = pLineFClass.CreateFeatureBuffer

If pPointFClass.FeatureCount(Nothing) > 1 Then
    CreateLine(Nothing)
End If

Private Sub CreateLine(ByVal pQFilter As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IQueryFilter)

  Dim pRowCursor As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeatureCursor
  Dim pFeature As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeature
  Dim pFirstPointShape As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IGeometry
  Dim pFirstPoint As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IPoint
  Dim pSecondPointShape As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IGeometry
  Dim pSecondPoint As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IPoint
  Dim pLine As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.ILine
  Dim pSegColl As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.ISegmentCollection
  Dim pGeomColl As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IGeometryCollection
  Dim pPolyline As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IPolyline
  Dim Counter As Integer

  pRowCursor = pPointFClass.Search(pQFilter, False)
  pFeature = pRowCursor.NextFeature
  Do Until pFeature Is Nothing
    pFirstPointShape = pFeature.Shape
    pFirstPoint = pFirstPointShape

    pFeature = pRowCursor.NextFeature
    If pFeature Is Nothing Then Exit Do
    pSecondPointShape = pFeature.Shape
    pSecondPoint = pSecondPointShape
    pLine = CreateSegment(pFirstPoint, pSecondPoint)
    pSegColl = New ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.Path
    pSegColl.AddSegment(pLine)
    pGeomColl = New ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.Polyline
    pGeomColl.AddGeometry(pSegColl)
    pPolyline = pGeomColl

    pIFBuffer.Shape = pPolyline
    pIFCursor.InsertFeature(pIFBuffer)
  Loop

End Sub

Private Function CreateSegment(ByRef pPointFrom As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IPoint, ByVal pPointTo As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IPoint) As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.ILine
    CreateSegment = New ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.Line
    CreateSegment.PutCoords(pPointFrom, pPointTo)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by using IPointCollection to get points from the point feature class , and then casting pointcollection into IPolyline. 
 protected override void OnClick()
        {

```
        IMxDocument pMxDocument = ArcMap.Document;
        IMap pMap = pMxDocument.FocusMap;
        ILayer player = pMap.get_Layer(0);
        IFeatureLayer pFeatureLayer = (IFeatureLayer)player;

        IPoint point = new Point();
        IPointCollection4 pPointColl = new PolylineClass();
        IGeometry ppointshape = (IGeometry)point;


        IFeatureCursor pRowCursor = pFeatureLayer.Search(null, false);
        IFeature pFeature = pRowCursor.NextFeature();





         do
         {
             ppointshape = pFeature.Shape;
             point = (IPoint)ppointshape;
                 pPointColl.AddPoint(point);


                  pFeature = pRowCursor.NextFeature();
             } while (pFeature != null);

         IPolyline ppolyline = new PolylineClass();
         ppolyline = (IPolyline)pPointColl;
         IMxDocument mxdoc = ArcMap.Application.Document as IMxDocument;
         IActiveView activeView = mxdoc.ActiveView;
         IScreenDisplay screenDisp = activeView.ScreenDisplay;
         short screenCache = Convert.ToInt16(esriScreenCache.esriNoScreenCache);
         screenDisp.StartDrawing(screenDisp.hDC, screenCache);

         IRgbColor color = new RgbColor();
         color.Red = 244; color.Blue = 0; color.Green = 0;

         ISimpleLineSymbol simpleLineSymbol = new SimpleLineSymbol();
         simpleLineSymbol.Color = color;
         simpleLineSymbol.Width = 1;

         screenDisp.SetSymbol(simpleLineSymbol as ISymbol);
         screenDisp.DrawPolyline(ppolyline);

       //  screenDisp.FinishDrawing();
        ArcMap.Application.CurrentTool = null;
    }
```